# Upgrade from IBM Application Center 6.1.0.2 to MFPF AppCenter 7.0

Tags: worklight-appcenter, mobilefirst-appcenter

I have WorkLight 6.1.0.2 and App Center client in my environment. We are migrating from 6.1.0.2 to MobileFirst 7.0.

I see list of upgrade db sql script in the installation directory of MobileFirst 7.0.

As i have lots of applications hosted in our 6.1.0.2 App Center, i want to manually upgrade it to 7.0. Not sure about which upgrade script need to be run from the list.

- upgrade-appcenter-60-61-db2.sql
- upgrade-appcenter-61-62-db2.sql
- upgrade-appcenter-62-63-db2.sql
- upgrade-appcenter-63-70-db2.sql
- upgrade-appcenter-505-506-db2.sql
- upgrade-appcenter-506-60-db2.sql

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run several scripts in a sequence:

- upgrade-appcenter-61-62-db2.sql
- upgrade-appcenter-62-63-db2.sql
- upgrade-appcenter-63-70-db2.sql

The first script updates the data base from 6.1.x to 6.2.x, the second from 6.2.x to 6.3.x and the last one from 6.3.x to 7.0.x.Hence, if you applied all three scripts in the right order, you upgrade from 6.1.0.2 to 7.0.

General reminder: before any upgrade, it is advisable to backup the data base, in order to be able to restore if something goes wrong!

Comment: Hi Georg, Thanks. I will try this in my QA environment and post you my findings. Thanks again.

Comment: Perfect. It worked. Migrated to IBM App Center 6.1.0.2 to 7.0. Thanks Georg.