# IBM Application Center APK upload failed

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-appcenter

My IBM Application Center version 7.0.0.00-20150729-1801

Trying to upload the App Center Client APK file to App Center Console. It fails with an error - FWLAC0000E: A server error was detected.

[image: Upload Failed Error]

[image: Android AAPT - Configured properly]

> [8/16/15 23:16:35:510 CDT] 00000129 UploadService I   file uploaded
>   [8/16/15 23:16:52:661 CDT] 00000129 ApplicationSe E   {
>           "id": "223b252a-a3aa-443d-9472-49e413d4af1c",
>           "message": "FWLAC0000E: A server error was detected.",
>           "params": [
>           ],
>           "productVersion": "7.0.0.00-20150729-1801"
>   }
>                                    com.ibm.puremeap.resources.exceptions.SystemException: The field "aclApp" of instance "com.ibm.puremeap.jpa.entity.AclAppPrincipalEntity[ id=unknown ]" contained a null value; the metadata for this field specifies that nulls are illegal.
>           at com.ibm.puremeap.resources.data.impl.ApplicationHelper.createApplicationImpl(ApplicationHelper.java:1741)
>           at com.ibm.puremeap.resources.data.impl.ApplicationHelper.createApplication(ApplicationHelper.java:1628)
>           at com.ibm.puremeap.artifacts.Application.create(Application.java:497)
>           at com.ibm.puremeap.services.ApplicationService.**create**(ApplicationService.java:154)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.InvokeMethodHandler.handleRequest(InvokeMethodHandler.java:63)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:33)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.CreateInvocationParametersHandler.handleRequest(CreateInvocationParametersHandler.java:54)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:34)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleResourceMethod(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:151)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:65)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceLocator(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:235)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:115)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceLocator(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:235)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:115)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindRootResourceHandler.handleRequest(FindRootResourceHandler.java:95)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.HeadMethodHandler.handleRequest(HeadMethodHandler.java:53)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.OptionsMethodHandler.handleRequest(OptionsMethodHandler.java:46)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.SearchResultHandler.handleRequest(SearchResultHandler.java:33)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.ResourceInvocation.handleRequest(ResourceInvocation.java:92)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.Requests.handleRequest(Requests.java:76)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.run(AbstractHandlersChain.java:60)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequestWithoutFaultBarrier(RequestProcessor.java:207)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:154)
>           at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:124)
>           at com.ibm.puremeap.services.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:56)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
>           at com.ibm.puremeap.services.RestFilter.doFilter(RestFilter.java:60)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:939)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
>           at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
>           at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
>           at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
>           at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
>           at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
>           at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1881)
>   Caused by:  org.apache.openjpa.persistence.InvalidStateException: The field "aclApp" of instance "com.ibm.puremeap.jpa.entity.AclAppPrincipalEntity[ id=unknown ]" contained a null value; the metadata for this field specifies that nulls are illegal.
>           at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.SingleFieldManager.preFlush(SingleFieldManager.java:567)
>           at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.SingleFieldManager.preFlush(SingleFieldManager.java:505)
>           at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.preFlush(StateManagerImpl.java:3059)
>           at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.SingleFieldManager.preFlushPC(SingleFieldManager.java:808)
>           at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.SingleFieldManager.preFlushPCs(SingleFieldManager.java:762)
>           at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.SingleFieldManager.preFlush(SingleFieldManager.java:656)
>           at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.SingleFieldManager.preFlush(SingleFieldManager.java:589)
>           at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.SingleFieldManager.preFlush(SingleFieldManager.java:505)
>           at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.preFlush(StateManagerImpl.java:3059)
>           at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.PDirtyState.beforeFlush(PDirtyState.java:39)
>           at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.beforeFlush(StateManagerImpl.java:1075)
>           at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flush(BrokerImpl.java:2127)
>           at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flushSafe(BrokerImpl.java:2087)
>           at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flush(BrokerImpl.java:1858)
>           at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.assignObjectId(StateManagerImpl.java:602)
>           at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.assignField(StateManagerImpl.java:689)
>           at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.beforeAccessField(StateManagerImpl.java:1696)
>           at com.ibm.ws.persistence.kernel.WsJpaStateManagerImpl.beforeAccessField(WsJpaStateManagerImpl.java:109)
>           at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.accessingField(StateManagerImpl.java:1627)
>           at com.ibm.puremeap.jpa.entity.AclAppPrincipalEntity.pcGetid(AclAppPrincipalEntity.java)
>           at com.ibm.puremeap.jpa.entity.AclAppPrincipalEntity.equals(AclAppPrincipalEntity.java:201)
>           at java.util.ArrayList.contains(ArrayList.java:309)
>           at com.ibm.puremeap.jpa.entity.AclApplicationEntity.addPrincipal(AclApplicationEntity.java:253)
>           at com.ibm.puremeap.jpa.entity.AclApplicationEntity.addAccessRightForPrincipal(AclApplicationEntity.java:195)
>           at com.ibm.puremeap.resources.data.impl.ApplicationHelper.getUpdatedACLOnCreate(ApplicationHelper.java:648)
>           at com.ibm.puremeap.resources.data.impl.ApplicationHelper.createApplicationImpl(ApplicationHelper.java:1734)
>           ... 86 more

Comment: Applied all the required 32 bit libraries glibc.i686, glibc-devel.i686, libstdc++.i686, zlib-devel.i686, ncurses-devel.i686, libX11-devel.i686, libXrender.i686, libXrandr.i686 and redeployed the Application Center and configured android.aapt.dir

Comment: I follow the below thread to upgrade my Application Center 6.1.0.2 to   
App Center 7.0 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31992264/upgrade-from-ibm-application-center-6-1-0-2-to-mfpf-appcenter-7-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log shows that this is a database problem, probably caused by OpenJPA. I suspect that a wrong version of OpenJPA is used in Websphere. This can be detected in the log, for instance if you see a message in the log such as

```
INFO [server.startup : 2] openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 2.x
```

As of MobileFirst 7.0 and earlier, the correct OpenJPA version must be 1.2.2, not 2.x (2.2.3 or similar).

This error typically occurs if the parentLast classloader policy is not set for the applicationcenter.war. For WAS Full Profile, see [step 5 here](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/t_configuring_websphere_application_server_for_appcenter_manually.html). For WAS Liberty Profile, see [the element <classloader delegation="parentLast"> here.](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/t_configuring_liberty_profile_for_appcenter_manually.html)