# IBM Mobile Firsts 7.1.0 - Error to deploy in AppCenter

Tags: android, mysql, ibm-mobilefirst

When performing uploading of the apk file, we get the error below:

> FWLAC0000E: A server error was detected.
>   [Com.ibm.puremeap.resources.exceptions.SystemException: null source]

[image]

Production Environment - Java 8 SDK
WebSphere Application Server V8.5.5.8
MySQL 5.6

Stacktrace:

```
********************************************************************************
product = WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.8 (wlp-1.0.11.cl50820151201-1942)
wlp.install.dir = E:/MobileFirst/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/
java.home = E:\StoneSales\bin\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre
java.version = 1.8.0_25
java.runtime = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (1.8.0_25-b18)
os = Windows Server 2008 R2 (6.1; amd64) (en_US)
process = 2192@PLUTAO
********************************************************************************
[25/02/16 09:21:38:531 BRT] 00000001 com.ibm.ws.kernel.launch.internal.FrameworkManager           A CWWKE0001I: The server appServer has been launched.
[25/02/16 09:21:42:063 BRT] 00000001 com.ibm.ws.kernel.launch.internal.FrameworkManager           I CWWKE0002I: The kernel started after 4,043 seconds
[25/02/16 09:21:42:391 BRT] 00000019 com.ibm.ws.kernel.feature.internal.FeatureManager            I CWWKF0007I: Feature update started.
[25/02/16 09:21:44:469 BRT] 00000011 com.ibm.ws.security.ready.internal.SecurityReadyServiceImpl  I CWWKS0007I: The security service is starting...
[25/02/16 09:21:45:157 BRT] 00000011 com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.monitor.DropinMonitor        A CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring dropins for applications. 
[25/02/16 09:21:45:594 BRT] 00000022 com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.TCPChannel                    I CWWKO0219I: TCP Channel defaultHttpEndpoint has been started and is now listening for requests on host *  (IPv6) port 9080.
[25/02/16 09:21:46:610 BRT] 0000001a com.ibm.ws.security.ready.internal.SecurityReadyServiceImpl  I CWWKS0008I: The security service is ready.
[25/02/16 09:21:46:610 BRT] 0000001a com.ibm.ws.security.token.ltpa.internal.LTPAKeyCreator       I CWWKS4105I: LTPA configuration is ready after 0,379 seconds.
[25/02/16 09:21:47:485 BRT] 00000011 com.ibm.ws.cache.ServerCache                                 I DYNA1001I: WebSphere Dynamic Cache instance named baseCache initialized successfully.
[25/02/16 09:21:47:500 BRT] 00000011 com.ibm.ws.cache.ServerCache                                 I DYNA1071I: The cache provider default is being used.
[25/02/16 09:21:47:500 BRT] 00000011 com.ibm.ws.cache.CacheServiceImpl                            I DYNA1056I: Dynamic Cache (object cache) initialized successfully.
[25/02/16 09:21:47:719 BRT] 0000001b com.ibm.ws.app.manager.AppMessageHelper                      I CWWKZ0018I: Starting application appcenterconsole.
[25/02/16 09:21:47:719 BRT] 00000021 com.ibm.ws.app.manager.AppMessageHelper                      I CWWKZ0018I: Starting application applicationcenter.
[25/02/16 09:22:10:986 BRT] 00000021 m.ibm.ws.container.service.app.deploy.ManifestClassPathUtils W SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jaxb-api.jar can not be found in jar file file:/E:/MobileFirst/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/servers/appServer/apps/expanded/applicationcenter.war/WEB-INF/lib/ibm_web20_jaxb-1.0.2.0-20110217.jar or its parent.
[25/02/16 09:22:10:986 BRT] 00000021 m.ibm.ws.container.service.app.deploy.ManifestClassPathUtils W SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jaxb-impl.jar can not be found in jar file file:/E:/MobileFirst/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/servers/appServer/apps/expanded/applicationcenter.war/WEB-INF/lib/ibm_web20_jaxb-1.0.2.0-20110217.jar or its parent.
[25/02/16 09:22:10:986 BRT] 00000021 m.ibm.ws.container.service.app.deploy.ManifestClassPathUtils W SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jsr173_1.0_api.jar can not be found in jar file file:/E:/MobileFirst/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/servers/appServer/apps/expanded/applicationcenter.war/WEB-INF/lib/ibm_web20_jaxb-1.0.2.0-20110217.jar or its parent.
[25/02/16 09:22:10:986 BRT] 00000021 m.ibm.ws.container.service.app.deploy.ManifestClassPathUtils W SRVE9967W: The manifest class path activation.jar can not be found in jar file file:/E:/MobileFirst/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/servers/appServer/apps/expanded/applicationcenter.war/WEB-INF/lib/ibm_web20_jaxb-1.0.2.0-20110217.jar or its parent.
[25/02/16 09:22:14:064 BRT] 00000021 m.ibm.ws.container.service.app.deploy.ManifestClassPathUtils W SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jaxb-api.jar can not be found in jar file file:/E:/MobileFirst/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/servers/appServer/apps/expanded/applicationcenter.war/WEB-INF/lib/ibm_web20_jaxb-1.0.2.0-20110217.jar or its parent.
[25/02/16 09:22:14:080 BRT] 00000021 m.ibm.ws.container.service.app.deploy.ManifestClassPathUtils W SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jaxb-impl.jar can not be found in jar file file:/E:/MobileFirst/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/servers/appServer/apps/expanded/applicationcenter.war/WEB-INF/lib/ibm_web20_jaxb-1.0.2.0-20110217.jar or its parent.
[25/02/16 09:22:14:080 BRT] 00000021 m.ibm.ws.container.service.app.deploy.ManifestClassPathUtils W SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jsr173_1.0_api.jar can not be found in jar file file:/E:/MobileFirst/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/servers/appServer/apps/expanded/applicationcenter.war/WEB-INF/lib/ibm_web20_jaxb-1.0.2.0-20110217.jar or its parent.
[25/02/16 09:22:14:080 BRT] 00000021 m.ibm.ws.container.service.app.deploy.ManifestClassPathUtils W SRVE9967W: The manifest class path activation.jar can not be found in jar file file:/E:/MobileFirst/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/servers/appServer/apps/expanded/applicationcenter.war/WEB-INF/lib/ibm_web20_jaxb-1.0.2.0-20110217.jar or its parent.
[25/02/16 09:22:14:846 BRT] 0000001b com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.webapp.WebGroup                 I SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: ApplicationCenterConsole.
[25/02/16 09:22:14:846 BRT] 0000001b com.ibm.ws.webcontainer                                      I SRVE0250I: Web Module ApplicationCenterConsole has been bound to default_host.
[25/02/16 09:22:14:846 BRT] 0000001b com.ibm.ws.http.internal.VirtualHostImpl                     A CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://plutao.mdsistemas.com.br:9080/appcenterconsole/
[25/02/16 09:22:14:924 BRT] 0000001b com.ibm.ws.app.manager.AppMessageHelper                      A CWWKZ0001I: Application appcenterconsole started in 27,205 seconds.
[25/02/16 09:22:17:768 BRT] 0000001c com.ibm.ws.app.manager.AppMessageHelper                      A CWWKZ0022W: Application applicationcenter has not started in 30,049 seconds.
[25/02/16 09:22:18:002 BRT] 00000019 com.ibm.ws.kernel.feature.internal.FeatureManager            A CWWKF0012I: The server installed the following features: [servlet-3.0, jsp-2.2, ssl-1.0, jndi-1.0, jdbc-4.0, distributedMap-1.0, appSecurity-2.0].
[25/02/16 09:22:18:002 BRT] 00000019 com.ibm.ws.kernel.feature.internal.FeatureManager            I CWWKF0008I: Feature update completed in 35,945 seconds.
[25/02/16 09:22:18:002 BRT] 00000019 com.ibm.ws.kernel.feature.internal.FeatureManager            A CWWKF0011I: The server appServer is ready to run a smarter planet.
[25/02/16 09:22:50:488 BRT] 00000021 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.webapp.WebGroup                 I SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: ApplicationCenterServices.
[25/02/16 09:22:50:488 BRT] 00000021 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer                                      I SRVE0250I: Web Module ApplicationCenterServices has been bound to default_host.
[25/02/16 09:22:50:488 BRT] 00000021 com.ibm.ws.http.internal.VirtualHostImpl                     A CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://plutao.mdsistemas.com.br:9080/applicationcenter/
[25/02/16 09:22:50:551 BRT] 00000021 com.ibm.ws.app.manager.AppMessageHelper                      A CWWKZ0001I: Application applicationcenter started in 62,832 seconds.
[25/02/16 09:25:25:606 BRT] 0000004b com.ibm.ws.session.WASSessionCore                            I SESN8501I: The session manager did not find a persistent storage location; HttpSession objects will be stored in the local application server's memory.
[25/02/16 09:25:25:622 BRT] 0000004b com.ibm.ws.session.WASSessionCore                            I SESN0176I: A new session context will be created for application key default_host/appcenterconsole
[25/02/16 09:25:25:653 BRT] 0000004b com.ibm.ws.util                                              I SESN0172I: The session manager is using the Java default SecureRandom implementation for session ID generation.
[25/02/16 09:25:25:684 BRT] 0000004b com.ibm.ws.jsp                                               I JSPG8502I: The value of the JSP attribute jdkSourceLevel is "15".
[25/02/16 09:25:25:809 BRT] 0000004b com.ibm.ws.cache.CacheServiceImpl                            I DYNA1056I: Dynamic Cache (object cache) initialized successfully.
[25/02/16 09:25:25:903 BRT] 0000004b com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet                              I SRVE0242I: [appcenterconsole] [/appcenterconsole] [servicesServlet]: Initialization successful.
[25/02/16 09:25:41:388 BRT] 0000004d com.ibm.puremeap.util.PureMeapBaseUtil                       I Resource conf/jndi/default.properties not found. This is not an error. Context path is /applicationcenter
[25/02/16 09:25:41:576 BRT] 0000004d com.ibm.appcenter.servlet.ConsoleServicesServlet             I The endpoint used to invoke the ApplicationCenter administration services is http://localhost:9080/applicationcenter
[25/02/16 09:25:44:170 BRT] 00000047 com.ibm.ws.session.WASSessionCore                            I SESN0176I: A new session context will be created for application key default_host/applicationcenter
[25/02/16 09:25:44:170 BRT] 00000047 com.ibm.ws.util                                              I SESN0172I: The session manager is using the Java default SecureRandom implementation for session ID generation.
[25/02/16 09:25:44:170 BRT] 00000047 com.ibm.ws.jsp                                               I JSPG8502I: The value of the JSP attribute jdkSourceLevel is "15".
[25/02/16 09:25:45:592 BRT] 00000047 com.ibm.puremeap.listeners.AppCenterServletContextListener   I Resource conf/jndi/default.properties not found. This is not an error. Context path is /applicationcenter
[25/02/16 09:25:45:654 BRT] 00000047 com.ibm.puremeap.util.DataUtil                               I getAppcenterProperties Read properties file. allProperties: {appcenter.jndi.name=java:comp/env/jdbc/AppCenterDS}
[25/02/16 09:25:45:685 BRT] 00000047 com.ibm.puremeap.util.DataUtil                               I dereferenceProperties Handling propName=appcenter.jndi.name propValue=java:comp/env/jdbc/AppCenterDS
[25/02/16 09:25:45:717 BRT] 00000047 com.ibm.ws.jca.cm.ConnectorService                           I J2CA8050I: An authentication alias should be used instead of defining a user name and password on dataSource[default-0].
[25/02/16 09:25:46:326 BRT] 00000047 com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.DSConfigHelper                          W DSRA0174W: Warning: GenericDataStoreHelper is being used.
[25/02/16 09:25:46:795 BRT] 00000047 com.ibm.ws.recoverylog.spi.RecoveryDirectorImpl              I CWRLS0010I: Performing recovery processing for local WebSphere server (Server).
[25/02/16 09:25:47:139 BRT] 00000047 com.ibm.ws.recoverylog.spi.RecoveryDirectorImpl              I CWRLS0012I: All persistent services have been directed to perform recovery processing for this WebSphere server (Server).
[25/02/16 09:25:47:139 BRT] 0000004f com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.RecoveryManager                          I WTRN0135I: Transaction service recovering no transactions.
[25/02/16 09:25:47:311 BRT] 00000047 com.ibm.puremeap.util.DataUtil                               I getDataSource Returning Data Source based upon jndiName=java:comp/env/jdbc/AppCenterDS dataSource=com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource@45de798d
[25/02/16 09:25:47:857 BRT] 00000047 com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper      I DSRA8203I: Database product name : MySQL
[25/02/16 09:25:47:857 BRT] 00000047 com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper      I DSRA8204I: Database product version : 5.6.24-log
[25/02/16 09:25:47:857 BRT] 00000047 com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper      I DSRA8205I: JDBC driver name  : MySQL-AB JDBC Driver
[25/02/16 09:25:47:857 BRT] 00000047 com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper      I DSRA8206I: JDBC driver version  : mysql-connector-java-5.1.6 ( Revision: ${svn.Revision} )
[25/02/16 09:25:47:936 BRT] 00000047 SystemErr                                                    R dataBaseFromDataSource=true
[25/02/16 09:25:47:936 BRT] 00000047 SystemErr                                                    R dataBaseUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/APPCNTR
[25/02/16 09:25:47:936 BRT] 00000047 SystemErr                                                    R dataBaseDriver=MySQL-AB JDBC Driver
[25/02/16 09:25:47:936 BRT] 00000047 SystemErr                                                    R dataBaseDriverVersion=5.1
[25/02/16 09:25:47:936 BRT] 00000047 SystemErr                                                    R dataBaseProduct=MySQL
[25/02/16 09:25:47:936 BRT] 00000047 SystemErr                                                    R dataBaseVersion=5.6.24-log
[25/02/16 09:25:47:936 BRT] 00000047 SystemErr                                                    R dataBaseUser=root@localhost
[25/02/16 09:25:47:936 BRT] 00000047 com.ibm.puremeap.resources.data.impl.PureMeapData            I constructor Creating EntityManagerFactory for persistence-unit=appcenterdb-mysql with properties: {openjpa.ConnectionFactory=com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource@45de798d}
[25/02/16 09:25:49:889 BRT] 00000047 SystemErr                                                    R 219  appcenterdb-mysql  INFO   [Default Executor-thread-40] openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 1.2.2
[25/02/16 09:25:50:139 BRT] 00000047 SystemErr                                                    R 469  appcenterdb-mysql  INFO   [Default Executor-thread-40] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Using dictionary class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.MySQLDictionary" (MySQL 5.6.24-log ,MySQL-AB JDBC Driver mysql-connector-java-5.1.6 ( Revision: ${svn.Revision} )).
[25/02/16 09:25:54:108 BRT] 00000047 com.ibm.puremeap.resources.data.impl.UpgradeHelper           I Checking if database upgrade to 6.0 is needed
[25/02/16 09:25:54:123 BRT] 00000047 com.ibm.puremeap.resources.data.impl.UpgradeHelper           I Database upgrade not needed or already done
[25/02/16 09:25:54:123 BRT] 00000047 com.ibm.puremeap.listeners.AppCenterServletContextListener   I The AppCenter servlet is ready, starting the database cleaning every 24 HOURS
[25/02/16 09:25:54:139 BRT] 00000052 com.ibm.puremeap.listeners.AppCenterServletContextListener   I cleaning the database leaks at Thu Feb 25 09:25:54 BRT 2016
[25/02/16 09:25:54:155 BRT] 00000047 AppCenterServletContextListener                              I No update push configured for application center services.
[25/02/16 09:25:54:155 BRT] 00000047 com.ibm.puremeap.listeners.AppCenterServletContextListener   I FWLAC0599I: ========= Application Center Server version 7.1.0.00-20150913-2345 started.
[25/02/16 09:25:54:311 BRT] 00000047 org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet          I The system is using the com.ibm.puremeap.services.MobileServicesServlet JAX-RS application class that is named in the javax.ws.rs.Application init-param initialization parameter.
[25/02/16 09:25:54:998 BRT] 00000047 apache.wink.server.internal.application.ApplicationProcessor I The following JAX-RS application has been processed: com.ibm.puremeap.services.MobileServicesServlet
[25/02/16 09:25:54:998 BRT] 00000047 org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.Resources                I The server has registered the JAX-RS resource class com.ibm.puremeap.services.MobileServices with @Path(/).
[25/02/16 09:25:55:108 BRT] 00000047 org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.Providers                I The class com.ibm.puremeap.util.ByteArrayWorkaroundProvider was registered as a JAX-RS MessageBodyReader provider for com.ibm.puremeap.util.ByteArrayWorkaround Java types and */* media types.
[25/02/16 09:25:55:108 BRT] 00000047 org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.Providers                I The class com.ibm.puremeap.util.ByteArrayWorkaroundProvider was registered as a JAX-RS MessageBodyWriter provider for com.ibm.puremeap.util.ByteArrayWorkaround Java types and */* media types.
[25/02/16 09:25:55:670 BRT] 00000047 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet                              I SRVE0242I: [applicationcenter] [/applicationcenter] [MobileServicesServlet]: Initialization successful.
[25/02/16 09:26:26:016 BRT] 00000057 com.ibm.puremeap.services.UploadService                      I file uploaded
[25/02/16 09:26:39:829 BRT] 0000004a com.ibm.puremeap.services.ApplicationService                 E {
    "id": "c7405daa-4627-44af-bd93-3165bfc20738",
    "message": "FWLAC0000E: A server error was detected.",
    "params": [
    ],
    "productVersion": "7.1.0.00-20150913-2345"
}
com.ibm.puremeap.resources.exceptions.SystemException: null source
    at com.ibm.puremeap.resources.data.impl.ApplicationHelper.createApplicationImpl(ApplicationHelper.java:1741)
    at com.ibm.puremeap.resources.data.impl.ApplicationHelper.createApplication(ApplicationHelper.java:1628)
    at com.ibm.puremeap.artifacts.Application.create(Application.java:497)
    at com.ibm.puremeap.services.ApplicationService.__create__(ApplicationService.java:154)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.InvokeMethodHandler.handleRequest(InvokeMethodHandler.java:63)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:33)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.CreateInvocationParametersHandler.handleRequest(CreateInvocationParametersHandler.java:54)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:34)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleResourceMethod(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:151)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:65)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceLocator(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:230)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:115)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceLocator(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:230)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:115)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindRootResourceHandler.handleRequest(FindRootResourceHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.HeadMethodHandler.handleRequest(HeadMethodHandler.java:53)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.OptionsMethodHandler.handleRequest(OptionsMethodHandler.java:46)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.SearchResultHandler.handleRequest(SearchResultHandler.java:33)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.ResourceInvocation.handleRequest(ResourceInvocation.java:92)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.Requests.handleRequest(Requests.java:76)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.run(AbstractHandlersChain.java:52)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequestWithoutFaultBarrier(RequestProcessor.java:207)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:154)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:133)
    at com.ibm.puremeap.services.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:56)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1287)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:778)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:475)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:150)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:93)
    at com.ibm.puremeap.services.RestFilter.doFilter(RestFilter.java:60)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:1020)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1142)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4867)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:297)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:997)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:262)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:955)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:341)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:470)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:404)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:284)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:174)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:504)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:574)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:929)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1018)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null source
    at java.util.EventObject.<init>(EventObject.java:56)
    at javax.sql.StatementEvent.<init>(StatementEvent.java:65)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4PreparedStatementWrapper.close(JDBC4PreparedStatementWrapper.java:70)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSRdbManagedConnectionImpl.destroyStatement(WSRdbManagedConnectionImpl.java:870)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSRdbManagedConnectionImpl.cacheStatement(WSRdbManagedConnectionImpl.java:2737)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.closeWrapper(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:354)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcObject.close(WSJdbcObject.java:185)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcObject.close(WSJdbcObject.java:141)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingPreparedStatement.close(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:139)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingPreparedStatement.close(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:139)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.ResultSetResult.close(ResultSetResult.java:189)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.strats.StoreCollectionFieldStrategy.load(StoreCollectionFieldStrategy.java:561)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.FieldMapping.load(FieldMapping.java:819)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.load(JDBCStoreManager.java:692)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingStoreManager.load(DelegatingStoreManager.java:116)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.ROPStoreManager.load(ROPStoreManager.java:78)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.loadFields(StateManagerImpl.java:2921)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.loadField(StateManagerImpl.java:2999)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.beforeAccessField(StateManagerImpl.java:1493)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.accessingField(StateManagerImpl.java:1478)
    at com.ibm.puremeap.jpa.entity.PrincipalEntity.pcGetauthoredAppCollection(PrincipalEntity.java)
    at com.ibm.puremeap.jpa.entity.PrincipalEntity.getAuthoredAppCollection(PrincipalEntity.java:484)
    at com.ibm.puremeap.jpa.entity.PrincipalEntity.addAuthoredApp(PrincipalEntity.java:503)
    at com.ibm.puremeap.resources.data.impl.Helper.update(Helper.java:214)
    at com.ibm.puremeap.resources.data.impl.ApplicationHelper.createApplicationImpl(ApplicationHelper.java:1733)
    ... 88 more
```

Comment: Is this issue common to all .apk files you are trying to upload or singular. Also, does other application binaries (.ipa/.xap etc) throw this error?

Comment: could you check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32042771/ibm-application-center-apk-upload-failed

Comment: yes, it's common to all .apk files. I just tried make a upload of an .apk file.

Comment: @NazmulHasan, my openJPA is on the 1.2.2 version.

Comment: From the stack trace, it seems to a problem with the data base, since the error comes from mysql when it tries to send an event. This event has no event source, and that's the exception. Hence: does any data base operation succeeds? For instance, try to create a new user group; this will trigger a data base operation. If that fails, then something is totally wrong with the data base.

Comment: Also, please check the parent-last classloader setting.
See https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/t_configuring_websphere_application_server_for_appcenter_manually.html
Check step 5 d and step 5 h for ApplicationCenterServices (applicationcenter.war) and ApplicationCenterConsole (appcenterconsole.war).

Answer (score 0):

Re-posting Georg Sander's suggestion from the comments:

> From the stack trace, it seems to a problem with the data base, since the error comes from mysql when it tries to send an event. This event has no event source, and that's the exception. Hence: does any data base operation succeeds? For instance, try to create a new user group; this will trigger a data base operation. If that fails, then something is totally wrong with the data base.
>
> Also, please check the parent-last classloader setting. See https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/t_configuring_websphere_application_server_for_appcenter_manually.html Check step 5 d and step 5 h for ApplicationCenterServices (applicationcenter.war) and ApplicationCenterConsole (appcenterconsole.war).

Comment: the problem was the connection driver of mysql. I was using the mysql-connector-java-5.1.6, so I changed for the mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin. Thanks, man.